# How do I create an event that Formik's handleChange will like?

Tags: reactjs, events, formik

The Formik bag provides event handlers like handleBlur, handleChange, for ordinary form items, we can assign like:

```
    <input name ="foo" onChange = {handleChange}/>
```

If I look more closely at that onChange event should be, like:

```
<input value = {values.foo} name="foo" onChange ={(e) => {
    console.log(e); 
    handleChange(e); //Formik still handles it
}}/>
```

We can see that it's a React [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) that is dispatched to formik.

The question is - if I've implemented my own component, say something like:

```
const Randomer = (props) => {
    const {onChange, name} = props; 
    const [value, setValue] = useState(Math.random() + ""); 
    return <div> 
         {value}
         <button onClick = {() => setValue(Math.random()+"")}> Click me</button> 
    </div> 
}
```

And I want to similarly allow Formik to be aware of the changes this component is making, how would I modify this code to do that?

[Code Sandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-maxwell-79itt)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I found the real answer:

- the Formik bag provides a function `setFieldValue` of the signature:

`(field: string, value: any, shouldValdidate? :boolean) => void`

You can use this to manually hook in formik field sets:

eg.

```
 <Randomer
    onChange={value => setFieldValue("random", value)}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, and I might be offbase on this*,is to add 'value' and 'name' to the button in your custom component:

```
const Randomer = props => {
  const { onChange, name } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(Math.random() + "");
  const handleClick = React.useCallback(
    event => {
      const newValue = Math.random() + "";
      setValue(newValue);
      onChange(event);
    },
    [onChange]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {value}
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        onChange={onChange}
      >
        {" "}
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

That way - you're still dispatching an ordinary form event, which happens to have a name and a value, and Formik is happy to accept it.

[Code Sandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-bush-35qvs)

* Apparently the best way to get the right answer on the internet, is to post the wrong answer.